# NSSreamstatus if i am getting data or not

Tags: objective-c, nsstream, nsinputstream

I  have NSInputStream , i want to check if i am getting data from other end , i read the NSStreamStatus , i cam across that "NSStreamStatusReading" is use to check the read data .

I tried to check that status but its not working can any one tell me how to check if i am getting data  or not 
.. 
code:

```
if([inputStream streamStatus]==NSStreamStatusReading)
{
NSlog(@"server is sending");
}
else
{
NSlog(@"no");
```

### }

its working when its sending  but when i stop server , its not updating .

Comment: is this code inside the stream: handleEvent: delegate method?

Comment: yes this is under handleevent

Comment: switch(event) {
            case (NSStreamStatus)NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
        {
        
            NSLog(@"%@",[stream streamError].localizedDescription);
        
        }
            break;      you can check errors with this code

Comment: I am using switch(streamEvent){case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:NSLog(@"stream Opened"); break; i want to check if i am getting any data or not  ...

Comment: you can add case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: to list. and print the length of data if data occurs